# python socketio emit data from another thread that IS NOT defined in the same code

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, flask-socketio

I'm going to be using websockets in a project i'm writing using python flask, so I'm trying to use socketio, I'm using this example as a template https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/master/example/app.py

It sets up a new thread defined in the same file as the routes and socketio.run as below and as expected each emit gets send out:

```
def background_thread():
    """Example of how to send server generated events to clients."""
    count = 0
    while True:
        socketio.sleep(10)
        count += 1
        socketio.emit('my_response',
                      {'data': 'Server generated event', 'count': count},
                      namespace='/test')
..
..
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    global thread
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = socketio.start_background_task(background_thread)
    emit('my_response', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0})
```

However I would like to have the background thread defined elsewhere in my code base, but when I move background_thread to another source file all the emits fail in socketio\base_manager.py emit (first line) because none of the rooms or namespaces have been set up.

What do I need to patch into the thread function to get the right contexts setup?

TIA.

(windows 10, python 3.7, flask 1.1.1, flask-socketio 4.2.1)

Comment: what do you mean by "fail"? Do you get an error? Please show the complete error message and stack trace then.

Comment: There are no errors, the failure is caused in the aforementioned source code, because none of the rooms or namespaces have been setup. The emit fails quietly because it doesn’t have the room I want to sent to in its dct of rooms.

Comment: Sorry, but this is very confusing. There are no reference to rooms in the code that you included in your question. You haven't even included the code that you say that fails, just the code that works well. I can't really help you unless you provide all the details.